# AngularJS: how to activate first non zero item in ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For an object like

```
 notification:  {
  "text":0,
  "image":2,
  "video":0
 }
```

I have a `ng-repeat` in view

```
<div ng-repeat="items in notification">
  // contents
</div>
```

how to assign an 'active' class to the first non zero notification type inside view?

**additional**
I know some approaches to handle it in controller or directives. I'm looking for a way to handle it inside view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) have own scope, so we can't simple define flag in [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) and set or clear it when first non zero item was found. But for solving we can use trick with [`$parent` property of `Scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$parent)

So see next code snippets:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.notification= {
        "text":0,
        "image":2,
        "video":1,
        "a":0
    };
});
```

```css
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="isFirst=true;">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in notification" ng-class="{active:isFirstActive }" ng-init="isFirstActive=$parent.isFirst&&v!=0;$parent.isFirst=$parent.isFirst&&v==0">
       {{k}}:{{v}}
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    $scope.notification= {
        "text":0,
        "image":2,
        "video":1,
        "a":0
    };
});
```

```css
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" >
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in notification" ng-class="{active:isFirstActive }" ng-init="isFirstActive=!$parent.isAcivated&&v!=0;$parent.isAcivated=$parent.isAcivated||v!=0">
       {{k}}:{{v}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, value) in notification" ng-class="{'active': value && hasOneActive}" ng-init="hasOneActive = hasOneActive || value;">
  // contents
</div>
```

**EDIT:** thanks [Grundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881286/grundy) for checking that script, i've corrected it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f70fwvm6/9/) but the new solution looks complicated

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="oldActive = false; newActive = false;">                    
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in notification" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-init="$parent.oldActive = $parent.newActive; $parent.newActive = !!($parent.newActive || v); 
                isActive = ($parent.newActive && !$parent.oldActive && ($index !== 0)) || ($parent.newActive && $index === 0)">
         //contents
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I need just one active class in all items of ngRepeat, the first none zero item. this adds for all non zero items.

Comment: I've corrrected it, move to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f70fwvm6/9/), please

Comment: it seems to be true, but as you say this solution looks complicated :-)